# PierfrancescoSoffritti:AndroidYouTubePlayer is not loading the video

Tags: android, listview, youtube

i am trying to load video from youtube using PierfrancescoSoffritti:AndroidYouTubePlayer but it failed to load error

i have tried the work done on the documentation of the library but not worked for me

```
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView=convertView.findViewById(R.id.video);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(initializedYouTubePlayer -> initializedYouTubePlayer.addListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReady() {
            initializedYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID, 0);
        }
    }), true);
```

the result would be the youtube video displayed on the list view but not got it

Comment: what are you passing in VIDEO_ID ?

Comment: the string id for the desired video